# Is it possible to set Collapsing layouts outside of AppBar / CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout

My client requested a collapsing view (triggered by a recycler view) that doesn't graphically belong to AppBar / Toolbar abstraction. While I was able to fake it somehow with the mentioned view sitting really inside CollapsingToolbarLayout, I really feel the code is clumsy and will be a nightmare to maintain.

The name CoordinatorLayout suggests that maybe the collapsing / parallax behaviour could be used anywhere in view hierarchy, but I couldn't find neither example nor any proof of in Android docs. All examples show collapsing views only inside AppBars!

So - is it or is it not possible to collapse any view anywhere with events from some RecyclerView?

Since it was requested - a schematic view of the layout. But the question is really more general. As stated above - I've implemented it putting the collapsable square inside AppBar and setting background to white. It works as required, but looks hacky...

[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample image of the layout so that someone can help you out.

Comment: This is good question. I had the same question at the early stages of my android development career. so +1

Answer (score 0):

> I really feel the code is clumsy and will be a nightmare to maintain.

I don't think so.

Also `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is optional (Remember, you can use `minHeight` if you want).

But you have to keep `AppBarLayout` to get things worked. (Don't forget to set `app:elevation="0dp"` to the `AppBarLayout`)

> Is it or is it not possible to collapse any view anywhere with events
>   from some `RecyclerView`?

Yes, it is possible. By attaching an `OnScrollListener` to the `RecyclerView` and manually collapsing it. But I think the `AppBarLayout` method will be enough for this.